# app can't write file on iPhone if the app is transfered to iPhone by ssh

Tags: iphone

I am using a jailbroken iPhone and i transfered an app to its /Applications.
I chmod the app to 0777.

The app can execute but this part of code acts differently on simulator and device.
on simulator,the length is the real length of the upload.jpeg,
But on device, the length become 0;

```
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *uploadFilePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"upload.jpeg"];

    [UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageForUpLoad,1) writeToFile:uploadFilePath atomically:YES];
    NSData* dataToUpload = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:uploadFilePath];
    int length = [dataToUpload length];
    UIAlertView* alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"jpeg length"
                                                    message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",length]
                                                   delegate:self
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
```

Comment: Why are you ssh-ing your application to the phone. Why not use Adhoc distribution of an iOS app?

Comment: I don't have a iOS developer ID yet, so I can't use Xcode to transfer my app to iPhone device.

Comment: If your device is jailbroken is that a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's a little tricky but I found where the problem lies.
change this:

```
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *uploadFilePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"upload.jpeg"];
```

to this:

```
NSString* uploadFilePath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"upload.jpeg"];
```

add it will be fine.
But I can't figure out why I can't use document directory on iOS 4.3 device.
When I use iOS 4.2 device, the former code is also OK.